# Hide Labels of Radio Buttons in Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates, radio-button

I have the following code in models.py:

```
MATRIX_COLUMN_CHOICES = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)]

class DeathCertificateReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    matrix_row_one_column_value = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.RadioSelect, choices = MATRIX_COLUMN_CHOICES)
```

And in my template I have the following:

```
{% for radio in form.matrix_row_one_column_value %}
    <li>{{ radio }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

6 radio button are being displayed which is correct but how do I display them without their labels? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting an empty `label` attribute on the model?

Comment: Easiest thing to do would be to hide it using `css`

Comment: I removed them from my choices in forms.py and it worked nicely. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is defined in the radio-select Widget https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect , so Creating a custom widget should do the trick. 
Also, it seems that your `<li></li>` tags are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. When you do a dir on the radio field you will see there is a tag option that only displays the input field. Therefore

```
{% for radio in form.matrix_row_one_column_value %}
    <li>{{ radio.tag }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

radio.tag should display just the radio input and NOT the label, note this was tested on Django 3.

Future tip, if you ever want to see what methods or attributes are available for an object just use dir(obj)